# Confusion over using LEAD/LAG window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, lag, lead

On this table:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id=53388829 LIMIT 10;
 id    |    lat     |    lon     | timestamp  | travelmode 
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------
 53388829 | 41.2371292 | -8.6711092 | 1459516801 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2371828 | -8.6710917 | 1459516806 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2371898 | -8.6710868 | 1459516811 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2370866 | -8.6711695 | 1459516816 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2370858 | -8.6711626 | 1459516821 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2370617 | -8.6711633 | 1459516826 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2371638 | -8.6709698 | 1459516831 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2371453 | -8.6711502 | 1459516836 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2370934 | -8.6711191 | 1459516841 |          0
 53388829 | 41.2370559 | -8.6711692 | 1459516846 |          0
(10 rows)
```

When I tried getting the difference using `LEAD/LAG` window function on `timestamp` column, the result is twice as I expect:

```
SELECT *, 
 LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) - (LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)) as diff
FROM mytable s where id=53388829 LIMIT 10
;
    id    |    lat     |    lon     | timestamp  | travelmode | diff 
----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------
 53388829 | 41.2371292 | -8.6711092 | 1459516801 |          0 |     
 53388829 | 41.2371828 | -8.6710917 | 1459516806 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2371898 | -8.6710868 | 1459516811 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2370866 | -8.6711695 | 1459516816 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2370858 | -8.6711626 | 1459516821 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2370617 | -8.6711633 | 1459516826 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2371638 | -8.6709698 | 1459516831 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2371453 | -8.6711502 | 1459516836 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2370934 | -8.6711191 | 1459516841 |          0 |   10
 53388829 | 41.2370559 | -8.6711692 | 1459516846 |          0 |   10
(10 rows)
```

Note: using `OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp)` in the window function does change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is subtracting the timestamp from the *next* row from the timestamp from the *previous* row.  You can eivide by 2:

```
SELECT s.*, 
       (LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) - (LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)) / 2 as diff
FROM mytable s 
WHERE id = 53388829
LIMIT 10;
```

Or use the timestamp from the current row:

```
SELECT s.*, 
       (LEAD(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) - timestamp) as diff
FROM mytable s 
WHERE id = 53388829
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Ah, OK. I  see the logic now.